# how to get text instead of value-php and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help in getting the text instead of value.

I have gone through all the websites some of them says use javascript into this.

This is the plugin.(si contact form)

Here if i do $_POST it gives [array([0]=>1)] only value not text.

Below is the code i have searched where they are framing.

```
$string .= '<option value="' . $opts_cnt.'  "' . $selected . '>'.esc_attr($opt).'</option>'."\n";
```

$opts_cnt ----->value

$esc_attr($opt)-------> text

i tried changing this way

```
$string .= ' <option value="' . $opts_cnt.' "." '.esc_attr($opt).' "' . $selected . '>'.esc_attr($opt).'</option>'."\n";
```

i tried in many permutation and combination ways.

"." if i am not inserting this its gives error message

At last i need the code to be in this format

```
 $string .= ' <option value="' . $opts_cnt.'  '.esc_attr($opt).' "' . $selected . '>'.esc_attr($opt).'</option>'."\n";
```

Even this is not working.

Comment: Can you give us the generated html of the select item please

Comment: Can't you just give the option a name attribute?

Comment: @Simon pollard It's a plugin.

Comment: @Humble Rat No I can't give .

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `value` attribute from the `option` tag then you should get the actual text for the `option`:

Try:

```
$string .= '<option ' . $selected . '>'.esc_attr($opt).'</option>'."\n";
```

Comment: if i do this it gives error in the application ..This field is required

Comment: Without heavily editing the plugin I don't think you'll be able to do this. Sorry.